# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) in third party API

Tags: jquery, api, cross-origin-read-blocking

today i was testing an api powered by "narrativa" but i'm stack at
"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response".
The code is quite simple: i'm just trying to make a get request with ajax and then display the response in the browser console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const URL = "https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2020-03-22/country/Italy/region/Umbria";

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

I' m not sure what is causing the problem because if i type that url in the browser the response is showed correctly.

Comment: Try a simple GET request ie. no `dataType` or `contentType`. Seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/oh62adfj/ . You aren't using JSONP in your example and the API returns JSON by default so the extra headers are not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it seems to work correctly.